# mysql I seek to eliminate all rows that do not contain the maximum date

Tags: mysql, select

I seek to eliminate all rows that do not contain the maximum date

this is my sql:

```
delete from campanya_baja where id in (select * from campanya_baja 
    where not fecha_campanya_baja = (select max(fecha_campanya_baja) from campanya_baja)
    group by id_contacto,id_usuario,id_emp_dato,fecha_campanya_baja);
```

when I execute this it gives me the following error:
    Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: In the future, please mark your code as code, this makes it easier for people to understand your question. I have done it for you, this time.

Comment: ohh thx and sorry.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, your question seems to be missing part of its last line. That's something that I can't edit in for you.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, you seem to want to delete all rows except for the latest per group. This is almost always quicker to achieve by creating a table with the rows you want to keep, and then replacing the old table with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your first subquery has fetch just one column (id):

```
delete from campanya_baja where id in (select id from campanya_baja 
where not fecha_campanya_baja = (select max(fecha_campanya_baja) from campanya_baja)
group by id_contacto,id_usuario,id_emp_dato,fecha_campanya_baja);
```